# How to read laravel_session cookies saved in cookie memory of browser in client side?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have an laravel and angular based application, I would like to read cookies from client to server side, But i can't read it. So can any one tell me how could I read the cookies.

Comment: Did you try "$val = Cookie::get('COOKIE_NAME');"?

Comment: By default laravel_session cookie is HTTP_ONLY so you can't manipulate them with js.

Comment: what is the solution @AlexSlipknot

Answer (score 3):

By default, `Laravel` enables Browser's HTTP-Only feature,
meaning the cookie is **not** accessible from `JavaScript`.

But that can be turned off,
by changing the default-value to `false` in the `config/session.php` file:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTP Access Only
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
| value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
| the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
|
*/

'http_only' => true,
```

Also note that laravel cookies are encrypted and decrypted on the fly by the application. Even if you read the cookie, it would be the encrypted value. If you need to access and modify certain cookies without encryption, then you need to add those cookies to the encryption except list.

You can add the cookies to skip encryption in the file `app/Http/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php`

```
protected $except = [
    //
];
```

Answer (score 1):

By default *laravel_session* cookie is **HTTP_ONLY** so you can't manipulate them with js. 
But you can change this flag in `your_project\config\session.php` by adding

```
'http_only' => false
```

Comment: @parthi and how do you try to get the cookie?

Comment: i just using this method ..Cookie::get('COOKIE_NAME');

Comment: @parthi so you are reading cookie in backend? Why? Cause you already have session variables and session's id

Comment: that's the good idea... but i have separate cookie thats shows on browser..

Comment: Mm, sorry, I didn't get it at all. What are you trying to get?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144826/discussion-between-parthi-and-alex-slipknot).

Comment: @parthi in the backend you can just get cookies with `$_COOKIE` variable or `Cookie::get()`

Answer (score -1):

I've just posted an answer to a related question which I think may also be relevant, as I believe you're dealing with the client cookies in server here: [How to work with cookies in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150022/how-to-work-with-cookies-in-laravel-5-2/46765993#46765993)